# How to get elevation profile data from Mapbox?

Tags: mapbox, elevation

my question is, how to get an elevation profile of the specified route from the *MapBox* service.

On the input we have path / route as the array of coordinates (latitute, longitute). As the result we would like to get the array of the pairs coordinate - elevation.

In case the resolution of elevation data is higher than the route coordinates provided, the result should contain also the elevation data between the original coordinates. The new points on the route would be generated according to the elevation data resolution. In case the resolution of elevation data is lower, it should interpolate the elevation values from the known data for the queried points. We would like to get results as precise as possible.

As the datasource for our solution we would like to use the *MapBox* service. However we did not find any documented *MapBox API* for this specific problem. We only found references to some [Surface API](https://blog.mapbox.com/plan-a-ride-with-surface-directions-and-turf-js-1fd6666709a1), that is no longer supported.

As we understand Mapbox now stores elevation data in the format of [Terrain-RGB](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/troubleshooting/access-elevation-data/) map tiles.
We identified the following steps to be able to solve our problem using *MapBox*:

1. Decode the route coordinates to the minimal set of map tiles.
2. Query the map tiles using *MapBox API*.
3. For each coordinate of the route, map it to the specific image pixel.
4. Translate the RGB color value of the pixel to the elevation in meters.

Is this algorithm correct? I think, that generating elevation profile for specific route is a common problem is there any tool that provides solution for our problem out of the box, maybe some SDK? Are we missing something? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 13):

### Short Answer

For the goal you have in mind, I would advise *not* using the Terrain-RGB raster tileset. Rather, you should use the [Tilequery API](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/#tilequery) to retrieve the elevation for the points along your route from the [Mapbox Terrain v2](https://docs.mapbox.com/vector-tiles/reference/mapbox-terrain-v2/) vector tileset.

### Longer answer

There are two possible sources and methods that can be used to retrieve elevation data from Mapbox, and the choice really depends on your needs. Both approaches are outlined in greater detail in troubleshooting documentation you've linked to: https://docs.mapbox.com/help/troubleshooting/access-elevation-data/

Here's the **tl;dr** for each approach:

#### 1. Retrieve the data from the [Terrain-RGB](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/how-mapbox-works/mapbox-data/#mapbox-terrain-rgb) *raster tiles*

This is the process you've outlined in your original question. This approach is good if you'd like to do things like styling hillshades accurately or generating a 3D mesh for a video game. Note that this method of not well suited for finding the elevation for specific lat/lon coordinate pairs.

#### 2. Retrieve the data from the [Mapbox Terrain v2](https://docs.mapbox.com/vector-tiles/reference/mapbox-terrain-v2/) *vector tiles*

This process requires you to request an elevation for each point along your route. You can do this by making requests to the [Mapbox Tilequery API](https://www.mapbox.com/api-documentation/maps/#tilequery). To your point about needing to interpolate coordinates between your route coordinates, you can use the [Turf.js library to "explode" your line geometry](https://turfjs.org/docs/#explode) into an array of coordinate pairs that you then pass to the Tilequery API one at a time. Most importantly, you retrieve the correct elevation data from the tileset by [parsing the response](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/troubleshooting/access-elevation-data/#get-elevation) you receive from the API request.

---

⚠️ Disclaimer: I currently work at Mapbox ⚠️

Comment: Thanks for answer. I queried the Mapbox Terrain v2 tile for a contour layer. The [result](https://www.dropbox.com/s/geifsua3wwef1xb/20190514_mapbox_terrain_v2_trnava.txt?dl=0) shows two __geometry objects__. They have all the same coordinates properties, the different is only the __index value__. What does the index value means? How can we interpolate the elevation from these values? Also the precision is 10 meters, would the Terrain-RGB not be more precise?

Comment: The results in the response are listed in order of proximity to the coordinates you pass in your request, so the first result will typically be the elevation of the contour polygon that your coordinate pair lies within. Yes, the terrain tileset is only precise up to 10 meters. If you require more precision, then the Terrain RGB (which is accurate up to 0.1m) will be your best bet - but it will require the more intensive workflow you outlined in your original post.

Comment: @kasi Did you ever implement this? I would love to see your example.

Comment: @NoahHuntington, yes I implemented some MVP, it is working, but currently, it is not publishable. Try to ping me in one/two months at stefan.kasala@kaps.sk